# Consolidating data in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two datasets that I am doing a left outer merge on in Pandas.  Here's the first:

```
                Name          Address
0  Joe Schmuckatelli  123 Main Street
1    Fred Putzarelli  456 Pine Street
2          Harry Cox  789 Vine Street
```

And the second:

```
           Address InvoiceNum
0  123 Main Street      51450
1  456 Pine Street      51389
2  789 Vine Street      58343
3  123 Main Street      52216
4  456 Pine Street  53124-001
5  789 Vine Street      61215
6  789 Vine Street  51215-001
```

The merged data looks like this:

```
                Name          Address InvoiceNum
0  Joe Schmuckatelli  123 Main Street      51450
1  Joe Schmuckatelli  123 Main Street      52216
2    Fred Putzarelli  456 Pine Street      51389
3    Fred Putzarelli  456 Pine Street  53124-001
4          Harry Cox  789 Vine Street      58343
5          Harry Cox  789 Vine Street      61215
6          Harry Cox  789 Vine Street  51215-001
```

Ideally I would like to have one line per address with all of the invoice numbers for that address in the third column, like this:

```
                Name          Address InvoiceNum
0  Joe Schmuckatelli  123 Main Street      51450, 52216
1    Fred Putzarelli  456 Pine Street      51389, 53124-001
2          Harry Cox  789 Vine Street      58343, 61215, 51215-001
```

The code I used to merge the data looks like this:

`mergedData = pd.merge(complaintData, invoiceData, on='Address', how='left')`

Is there a way to do this easily in Pandas or some other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can [`groupby aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) the values in `df2`by joining strings together for each Address before [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) / [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `df1`:

```
new_df = df1.join(
    df2.groupby('Address')['InvoiceNum'].aggregate(', '.join),
    on='Address',
    how='left'
)
```

`new_df`:

```
                Name          Address               InvoiceNum
0  Joe Schmuckatelli  123 Main Street             51450, 52216
1    Fred Putzarelli  456 Pine Street         51389, 53124-001
2          Harry Cox  789 Vine Street  58343, 61215, 51215-001
```

*Either [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) or [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) work here, although [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) has slightly less overhead in this case since the result of `groupby` has `Address` as the index.

---

Setup:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['Joe Schmuckatelli', 'Fred Putzarelli', 'Harry Cox'],
    'Address': ['123 Main Street', '456 Pine Street', '789 Vine Street']
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Address': ['123 Main Street', '456 Pine Street', '789 Vine Street',
                '123 Main Street', '456 Pine Street', '789 Vine Street',
                '789 Vine Street'],
    'InvoiceNum': ['51450', '51389', '58343', '52216', '53124-001', '61215',
                   '51215-001']
})
```

Comment: Absolutely bloody brilliant.  Works like a charm.  You have no idea how many days of screwing around you just saved me.  And this worked even though my setup was different - the data is getting fished from PDFs and comes in the form of lists of lists of single tuples because that's how re.findall() works.

Thank you thank you thank you.  I owe you a beer next time you're in a certain "anarchist jurisdiction" in the PNW. ;)